# External SATA PM (Port Multiplier) Enclosure w/ Mac Mini

Tags: mac, mac-mini

I'd love to use one of the new Mac Mini Server models as a backup server, but need a lot more space.

Has anybody tried attaching a port multiplied eSATA enclosure to the Mini? This is the one I'd really like to work: http://www.firmtek.com/seritek/seritek-5pm/

I've read a few things that imply that the system controller in the Mac Mini supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the SATA the Mac Mini does not support port multipliers. Technically the MCP79 in it can support port multipliers, but either the driver or the firmware does not enable it.

Comment: Bummer. That's what I figured.

Comment: And when port multipliers would be supported, there are issues to expect. We have seen "bus reset storms" in high io load situations with Silicon Image port multiplier chipsets on Mac OS X. With the Jmicron JMB393 chipset, S.M.A.R.T. readings of drive #1 (not port #1) are not readable.

Comment: wiki says all mac minis are on sata 1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini#Storage